# Why can't scipy compute all eigenvalues?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

The documentation of [scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs.html) reads

> The number of eigenvalues and eigenvectors desired. k must be smaller than N-1. It is not possible to compute all eigenvectors of a matrix.

Why can it not compute all eigenvalues? This is possible for standard (non-sparse) matrices.

Answer (score 2):

The [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs.html) also say:

> This function is a wrapper to the ARPACK SNEUPD, DNEUPD, CNEUPD, ZNEUPD, functions which use the **Implicitly Restarted Arnoldi Method** to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Digging into the [ARPACK docs](https://www.caam.rice.edu/software/ARPACK/UG/node50.html), the description of the algorithm says:

> The algorithm is capable of computing a few (k) eigenvalues with user specified features such as largest real part or largest magnitude using storage.

So this is a limitation of the algorithm, as [explained by the Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnoldi_iteration):

> The Arnoldi method belongs to a class of linear algebra algorithms that give a partial result after a small number of iterations, in contrast to so-called direct methods which must complete to give any useful results.

Comment: Thanks, though it seems to me that all three sources say the same thing and none explain *why* these methods can't compute all eigenvalues.

Comment: There are methods which compute all eigenvalues and others that compute only the largest ones (faster). Depending on your problem you may prefer one or the other. So the question is why Scipy chose to use the Arnoldi method when using sparse matrices. Probably because sparse matrices are useful only when they are large, the full eigenvalue solution has a very high computational cost, and the cost is even higher when using a sparse representation.